# Appending Column With value_counts() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have a dataframe named **output** that looks like as below :

```
   created_at
0  1/8/2017 0:00
1  1/8/2017 0:00
2  1/8/2017 0:00
3  1/8/2017 0:00
4  1/8/2017 0:00
5  1/8/2017 1:00
6  1/8/2017 2:00
7  1/8/2017 3:00
```

I wanted to count the number of times a particular time appears in the dataframe named **df3**. The result is as as below :

```
1/8/2017 0:00    5
1/8/2017 1:00    1
1/8/2017 3:00    1
1/8/2017 2:00    1
```

What I want is to have two headings added to the df3 called **created_at** and **count**.

What I first did was to remove the duplicates from the **output dataframe** and sorted the values, getting a result as below :

```
   created_at
0  1/8/2017 0:00
5  1/8/2017 1:00
6  1/8/2017 2:00
7  1/8/2017 3:00
```

Now I added the column **count** in the **output dataframe** but I get the result as below :

```
   created_at        count
0  1/8/2017 0:00     NaN
5  1/8/2017 1:00     NaN
6  1/8/2017 2:00     NaN
7  1/8/2017 3:00     NaN
```

What i want to achieve is a dataframe called **result** which should look like this :

```
   created_at        count
0  1/8/2017 0:00     5
5  1/8/2017 1:00     1
6  1/8/2017 2:00     1
7  1/8/2017 3:00     1
```

How do I do this? My code is as below :

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(path1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(path2)
output = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on="created_at")
df3 = output.created_at.value_counts()

output = output.drop_duplicates()
output = output.sort_values(by=['created_at'])
output['count'] = df3


print(output,'\n\n')
```

Any and all help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: The result df is not what I have, but is what my desired output is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `rename_axis` with `reset_index`, after calling `value_counts`.

```
df.created_at.value_counts().rename_axis('created_at').reset_index(name='count')

      created_at  count
0  1/8/2017 0:00      5
1  1/8/2017 2:00      1
2  1/8/2017 1:00      1
3  1/8/2017 3:00      1
```

---

Alternatively, use `groupby` + `agg`:

```
df.groupby('created_at').created_at.agg([('count', 'count')]).reset_index()

      created_at  count
0  1/8/2017 0:00      5
1  1/8/2017 1:00      1
2  1/8/2017 2:00      1
3  1/8/2017 3:00      1
```